# Azure Logic Apps HTTP response body to SQL row

Tags: json, azure, syntax, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

The question concerns Azure Logic Apps and how to parse JSON data in a workflow in order to store it to the sql database.

I have a problems to select content from JSON array that I'm receiving from HTTP request. Body is not empty because it's visible in previous step output. I would like to insert content to SQL database.
The question is that how can I choose a specific content from parse_JSON Body? What should I type in expression field?

```
{
   "key":"value",
   "key1": {
        "key1.1":"value",
        "key1.2":"value"
     },
   "key2":"value"
},
{
   "key":"value",
   "key1":"value",
   "key2":"value"
}
```

[image: Workflow]
[image: Expression field]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your json format is wrong, suppose it should be like the below.

```
[{
   "key":"value1",
   "key1": {
        "key1.1":"value2",
        "key1.2":"value3"
     },
   "key2":"value4"
},
{"key":"value",
   "key1":"value",
   "key2":"value"}]
```

Then is about the parse_json, if your json format is fixed, you could use `Parse_json`, mostly you could select the specific property from the dynamic content. And if not you could write the expression to implement. Like to get the value from `key1.1`, the expression should be `body('Parse_Json')[0]['key1']['key1.1']`, the `0` is the index in the array.

[image]

And if the format is not fixed, just use the `Compose` action, and compose could not select property with dynamic content so if want to get like `key4` value, the expression should be `outputs('Compose')[1]['key4']`.

[image]

And this is my test result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I managed to solve the problem by using Code View-window. In there I just typed "@items('For_each')?['key 1']?['key1.1']".

Comment: @Mr. H, I don't see the for_each action in your pic. So you need get the value in a loop?