# How to convert an image stored in azure blob storage to base 64 using adf or logicaapp

Tags: azure, base64, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I need to convert an image .png/.jpg files to base64 using adf or logicapp

New to azure..I need to convert an image .png/.jpg files to base64 and need to save the values in azure SQL database

Comment: Jump into LogicApps and give it a go.  If you have any ability at all, you'll make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the workaround I did to convert the Blob Files to base64 encoded string using Azure Logic Apps**:

[image]

You need to give your Azure Storage Account Name, Access Key and Container Name in the 1st 2 steps of the above Workflow.

**In Compose Step**, take the parameter which you need to convert to encoded format:
[image]

Next step, I taken Send Mail Connector for sending the ***encoded base 64 string*** of uploaded file or you can select other connectors like create a new blob and save into it.
In the body, gave the expression as `base64(outputs('Compose'))` for conversion of blob file content and clicked on save.

[image]

**Result**:

[image]

- To save in the SQL Database Row, use SQL Server connector in the next step - provide the SQL Server Name, Database Name, Username and password if authentication provided or Client Id, Tenant Id, Client Secret if Azure AD Authentication activated.
  [image]
- Select the **Insert Row (V2)** operation for inserting the data in the Table rows where you need to provide the Table name here.

**Refer to this [practical workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196461/azure-logic-apps-http-response-body-to-sql-row) regarding how to save the response data in SQL Server database table row using Azure Logic App Connectors.**